# Cacading Drop Down 2nd Dropdown name Not getting Change in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have mobile brand list .here based on 1st drop down 2nd dropdown list is coming but .when i select nokia in 1st dropdown ,Lumia 735,Asha 230,Lumia 510 these are coming in 2nd dropdown,in 2nd dropdown i have selected Lumia 735 its working fine but again i have selected Samsung in 1st dropdown here 2nd drop list got changed but already selected Lumia 735 still showing .
expectation:based on 1st dropdown selection 2nd dropdown should come
2.after 1st and 2nd dropdown selection ,when i submit i need to get id,brandname,modelname

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.filters'])
    .controller("myCntrl", function ($scope) {
   
    $scope.items= [{

        
        id: "986745",
        brandname: "Nokia",
        modelname: "Lumia 735",
  price: "7500"
       
    }, {
         
        id: "896785",
        brandname: "Nokia",
        modelname: "Asha 230",
  price: "12000"
    }, {
         
        id: "546785",
        brandname: "Nokia",
        modelname: "Lumia 510",
  price: "9500"
    },
    {
         
        id: "144745",
        brandname: "Samsung",
        modelname: "Samsung 110",
  price: "13000"
    },
    
    {
         
        id: "986980",
        brandname: "Samsung",
        modelname: "Galaxy A5",
  price: "5500"
    },
 {
         
        id: "586980",
        brandname: "Samsung",
        modelname: "Galaxy Note 4 Duos",
  price: "5500"
    },
 {
         
        id: "986980",
        brandname: "Samsung",
        modelname: "Galaxy A5",
  price: "5500"
    },
 {
         
        id: "586980",
        brandname: "Samsung",
        modelname: "Galaxy Note 4 Duos",
  price: "1000"
    },
 
 {
         
        id: "232980",
        brandname: "Htc",
        modelname: "One X9",
  price: "1000"
    },
 {
         
        id: "456798",
        brandname: "Htc",
        modelname: "Desire 820",
  price: "1000"
    }

    ]
    
     
    $scope.test = function()
{
console.log($scope.id);
console.log($scope.selectedBrand);
console.log($scope.selectedModel);

}
 
    
})

$(function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
    $("select").select2();
  }, 100);
}); 
//]]>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  
    <div ng-controller="myCntrl">
 <form name="addvehicleForm"   data-ng-submit="test()" novalidate>
        <label>List Of Brand</label>
        
    <label for="singleSelect"> select: </label>
  <select ng-model="selectedBrand">
        <option ng-repeat="item in items | unique: 'brandname'" value="{{item.brandname}}">{{item.brandname}}</option>
  </select>
    <select ng-model="selectedModel">
        <option ng-repeat="item in items | filter: {brandname: selectedBrand}" value="{{item.modelname}}">{{item.modelname}}</option>
  </select>
        
       
  
      <div class="padding">
            <button class="button  button-full button-stable"  type="submit"  > Save
            </button>                  
         </div> 
   </form>
    </div>
 
 
    
</div>
```

pls run above code and solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Seems all you want is to clear the model if you change the brand, to do that, just put ng-click on

```
<select ng-model="selectedBrand">
<option ng-repeat="item in items | unique: 'brandname'" value="{{item.brandname}}" 
               ng-click="setNull()">{{item.brandname}}</option>
</select>
```

and in script do something like

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.filters'])
    .controller("myCntrl", function ($scope) {

          $scope.setNull = function(){

               $scope.selectedModel = "";

          }
          .
          .
          .
```

Comment: There's no need to use a function for this. `ng-click="selectedModel=''"`

Comment: Pls update your answer in snippet or jsfiddle it would be useful for me